# Font Awesome doesn't work on subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I installed FontAwesome correctly on my wordpress page and the icons do show at the main page. But when it goes to a subdirectory like mydomain.com/subdirectory the items disappear.
Any ideas why?

I've implemented it this way in the header.php

```
<head>
(.....)

<!-- FONT AWESOME -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it worked when I used the referece from this page:
https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because `href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"` is a **relative** link and the CDN `href` value is an **absolute** (online, even) one?

If you replace 'font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' with '//yourdomain.com/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' or wherever you're serving it from, it'll likely work.

Of course, in WordPress, you should *probably* call `wp_enqueue_style()` in functions.php as described at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/ and maybe include Font Awesome in your theme folder. (It kind of depends on wether you'll be distributing the theme or if it's purely a one-time project.)